# Create a map activity inside android notification

Tags: android, android-activity, android-notifications

I want to show a live map inside an andriod notification. Is it possible to create a google map activity inside an android notification and pass it long lat values to show the location of a restaurant/location and an eta from that point ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, that is not possible, assuming that by "live map" you mean Maps V2's `MapView`. The `RemoteViews` that you can use in a `Notification` can only handle a few widgets, and `MapView` is not one of them.

You are welcome to use some sort of static map image generator and show that image in an `ImageView` in the `Notification`.

Note that even an expanded `Notification` is not all that large, so your map will be rather small.

Comment: thanks, is there a way to show a dynamic web link in the ImageView something link this http://bit.ly/1kYTlAM

Comment: @Mayank: I would not count on the process that displays a `Notification` to have the `INTERNET` permission. You could download the image yourself, though. Just be careful with the image size, as there is a 1MB "binder transaction" limit, and your `RemoteViews` must be smaller than 1MB.